# nautilus (files app) takes long time to start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus

I found that in my Ubuntu 18.04, nautilus takes a long time to start. Here is the trace of running it on the command line:

```
$ time nautilus
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2015.10.28
Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

real    0m40.316s
user    0m0.765s
sys 0m0.141s
```

I hope it might provide some clues to experts.

I also notice nautilus also causing other apps to start slow, such as gedit and chrome. 
I tried removing gvfs as well as nautilus will make starting other apps such chrome much faster. 
But I need a file manager.

Comment: I observe the same problem under Ubuntu 20.04 focal: 25s startup time…

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/1187377/94728 provides a solution

Comment: another good reference for the similar problem: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=230036

Comment: I had the same problem on my machine, at home I have NAS and an entry in /etc/fstab and everything was ok. When I went to the office (no NAS available) the opening of the files always took ~30sec until the timeout. After commenting out the entries in /etc/fstab I had no more delays.

Answer (score 13):

Update:

Problem solved,
After some try and error I found the guilty package.

Starting from `ubuntu 18.04.3` a package named `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` has been added to the release.

I don't know what is the package used for. No other packages depend on it; And I did't need it. Purging it using purge command `apt-get purge xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` solved the issue. Below you can find the output for time command like `time nautilus` for opening and closing it ASAP which shows it take about 29 seconds to open before purge and about 2 seconds after purging it.

```
Before
real    0m28.818s
user    0m0.678s
sys 0m0.402s

After
real    0m1.943s
user    0m0.885s
sys 0m0.156s
```

P.S: purging the package had no side effect on my system and Ubuntu works smoothly as expected.

---

History:

Suffering from same issue in 18.04.3,

To get rid of the problem and still have 18.04, you might downgrade to 18.04.2.

I did that, 18.04.2 works smoothly as expected and I have 18.04 as you asked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/989100)

Comment: Its not a question!

I know its not a complete answer, but I had to downgrade to 18.04.2 to get rid of the problem.
So I am using 18.04 (as the question needs).

Comment: That's fair enough, the comment is an automated one and does not quite fit. Having said that, this answer could do with a bit more explanation.

Comment: @mark-kirby I tried an edit, hope it does the job.

Comment: Solved my issue on Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

Comment: Also does the trick on Debian 11

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues after updating to Ubuntu 18.04. The solution for me was

- Install `net` with
  `sudo apt install samba-common-bin`
- then `sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/samba/usershares/`
- and `sudo chmod go+rwx /var/lib/samba/usershares/`