# ubuntu 19.10 crash when lazarus runs

Tags: gnome

Since I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 and lazarus 2.0.2 package, when I want to run Lazarus IDE, I have 30 seconds delay and then ubuntu freezes , mouse and keyboard no respond.
Can everybody help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The previously linked page [Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start), provides solutions that worked for me.

1. (Temporary Solution) Launch the program as the superuser:

   ```
   sudo ./project1
   ```
2. (Temporary Solution) Launch the application with launch:

   ```
   dbus-launch --exit-with-session ./project1
   ```
3. (Permanent Solution) Run the following command and restart your computer:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that Ubuntu 19.10 it experiencing some difficulties with Gtk2 applications, for some people (e.g. [Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start)).

I had the same experience you did (except using Lazarus 2.0.6 distributed from the Lazarus web page), as have others (see https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,47240.0.html).

The only way I was able to get Lazarus to work acceptably was to use fpcupdeluxe to build the Qt5 version of Lazarus, which seems to perform fine under 19.10.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait for better use of Gtk2