# 30 seconds to start up some programs

Tags: performance, 19.10

I have experienced with some apps, like Filezilla or Hexchat, that the loading times are obscene.

Look at [this video](https://webm.red/5cq4.webm). Trying to open up Filezilla, with syslog in the background and a timer. It takes about 30 seconds!

Webm: https://webm.red/5cq4.webm

Why could this be happening?? I am not using snaps, by the way.

**UPDATE #1**

```
~ 
➜ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions 
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 dbugger dbugger 4096 Nov 23 19:51 .
drwx------ 3 dbugger dbugger 4096 Nov 27 20:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 dbugger dbugger 4096 Nov 23 19:51 wsmatrix@martin.zurowietz.de

~ 
➜ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Okt 17 14:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov 23 19:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Okt 17 14:27 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Okt 17 14:27 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Okt 17 14:27 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

~ 
➜ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       6,9Gi       3,5Gi       422Mi       5,1Gi       7,9Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi        47Mi       2,0Gi
```

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE #2**

```
➜ sudo fdisk -l    
[sudo] password for dbugger: 
Disk /dev/loop0: 44,18 MiB, 46325760 bytes, 90480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 89,13 MiB, 93454336 bytes, 182528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 149,93 MiB, 157192192 bytes, 307016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 54,52 MiB, 57151488 bytes, 111624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 4,2 MiB, 4403200 bytes, 8600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 14,76 MiB, 15462400 bytes, 30200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 956 KiB, 978944 bytes, 1912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 54,52 MiB, 57151488 bytes, 111624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/sda: 232,91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 850 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x030e5be7

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sda2       1052670 488396799 487344130 232,4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 488396799 487344128 232,4G 83 Linux


Disk /dev/sdb: 232,91 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 840 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2468E9EA-E160-475B-9142-23542412F639

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048   1085439   1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sdb2  1085440   1290239    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sdb3  1290240   1323007     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb4  1323008 488396799 487073792 232,3G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 89,1 MiB, 93429760 bytes, 182480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 14,76 MiB, 15458304 bytes, 30192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 4,2 MiB, 4403200 bytes, 8600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 156,7 MiB, 164290560 bytes, 320880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**Update #3**

```
➜ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for dbugger: 
/dev/sda5: UUID="273d04d3-e79e-40c3-8d2a-c167d631934f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="030e5be7-05"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="42C9-4DE8" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="030e5be7-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="0AF82957F82941F5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="5486b80c-7110-4e9f-b464-2fb9860bb6fc"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="E629-871C" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="52305b07-3a42-4170-9e83-1311378a9117"
/dev/sdb3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="a3ecddd0-09ba-48f8-aa32-016bc79640d5"
/dev/sdb4: UUID="7CB42A3DB429F9F2" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="bfa1694b-1012-410a-a5a9-41e6ad30e6b9"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"

~ took 4s 
➜ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

~ 
➜ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=273d04d3-e79e-40c3-8d2a-c167d631934f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=42C9-4DE8  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

**Update #4**

```
➜ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
1002
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h`... and screenshot(s) of `Disks` app `SMART Data` window... two screenshots might be required to see all of the data.

Comment: Go to samsung.com and download their `Samsung Magician` and check the firmware in your SSD(s). Also... show me `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid`. Is your 2nd SSD a clone of the 1st one?

Comment: Yes, SM is Windows. Do you have that? Also, I updated my prior comment, plz take a look. Thanks!

Comment: What gets returned with `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`? Show me `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: I have done Update #3. The other SDD has Windows 10, but I cannot log in right now for other reasons. It should not be relevant to this problem. I can unplug it, and the problem persists.

Comment: The only reason to boot into Windows is to be able to run SM. In `terminal` to `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the output, and tell me the make/model # of your computer.

Comment: I can't log into windows right now. Would it work in a Virtualbox machine?

Comment: SM won't work in a VM, as it has no direct contact with the hardware. Plz let me know the answers to the 2nd part of my comment. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Updated.

Comment: Thanks, but I also needed the make/model # of your computer/motherboard, so I can go check for a newer BIOS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101569/discussion-between-enrique-moreno-tent-and-heynnema).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start)

Comment: I was focused on the Samsung SSD's as they've been know to require firmware updates... and I was focusing on the BIOS version because that effects everything. Did the answer in your dup question actually solve your problem?