# Various programs are starting slow on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: performance, 19.10

I am using Ubuntu now for a year and a half or so and never had any problems with the opening speed of any program. But now, after installing 19.10 I experience some serious issues with the speeds some programs are opening. The programs don't seem to have anything in common and even weirder, IntelliJ IDE is actually loading up pretty fast compared to them, and IntelliJ uses by far more resources.

Also the slow packages aren't snaps.

Programs that start normally:

- Terminal
- Firefox
- IntelliJ
- Atom
- Libreoffice

Programs that have issues starting up:

- VLC Player
- Filezilla
- Moeditor
- VirtualBox

I was told to use the `strace` command to see what calls are taking so long. I found that the following call occurs with all the slow starting programs:

```
poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000
```

(The number `fd=` is always some other one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module

If that does not work, try launching the program with dbus-launch --exit-with-session program_name

Another thread on this issue for more information:

[Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start/1189599#1189599) also [Fresh 19.10 install: FileZilla and Beyond Compare slow launch time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194788/fresh-19-10-install-filezilla-and-beyond-compare-slow-launch-time)

Comment: I have Ubuntu 20.04 and some programs are starting slow too 10-25sec. dbus-launch solved my problem. Now programs are starting immediately. Thanx.