# Fresh 19.10 install: FileZilla and Beyond Compare slow launch time

Tags: performance, 19.10, installed-programs, filezilla

Just installed a fresh install of 19.10 on a Ryzen 2600 with a solid state drive.  All seems to be well except FileZilla and Beyond Compare take a very long time to launch (about or more than 20 seconds)  Once the programs do launch, they seem to run with no problems and at full speed.  Other programs on the same computer (Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice, development tools, etc.) do not have this problem and launch in a few seconds.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing both of those programs, but did not help.  I tried switching window managers (Xubuntu, Cinnamon, Plasma) but the result was the same.  Made a new user account and still did not change.

The only thing I can do to get those two programs to launch quickly is to launch them on the command line with sudo (not a good solution)  When I launch them as sudo, both the programs will launch quickly within a few seconds.

Any ideas where to go in troubleshooting this?

Edit/Additional information:

I installed both programs using apt-get on the command line.  Filezilla is version 3.39.0 and Beyond Compare is version 4.3.3 (build 24545)

snap list | grep -Ei "FileZilla|Beyond" produced the output "No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'.

Comment: How did you installed FileZilla and Beyond Compare? Are they Snaps? Please add output of `snap list | grep -Ei "FileZilla|Beyond"` and `which filezilla; which bcompare` to the question.

Comment: When I ran the snap-list, it said "No snaps are installed yet. Try 'snap install hello-world'."

Comment: Installed Beyond Compare and Filezilla using apt-get on the command line

Comment: Filezilla is version 3.39.0 and Beyond Compare is version 4.3.3 (build 24545)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install appmenu-gtk2-module` (1)

`reboot`

1. taken from [Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start/1189599#1189599)

Comment: Thanks!  Installing appmenu-gtk2-module did not fix it for me, but using the dbus-launch -exit-with-session suggestion on the same page in your link makes both filezilla and beyond compare launch with no delay.

Comment: @esenge did you reboot after installing appmenu-gtk2-module?

Comment: Yes I did reboot after installing appmenu-gtk2-module, but unfortunately it left the launch times on those programs unchanged until I did  dbus-launch -exit-with-session to launch the program.