# Ubuntu 19.10 Slow response when run programs

Tags: 19.10

I have installed yesterday Ubuntu 19.10 and some programs need about 30 seconds or 1 minute to start. E.g WPS Office latest version when I click on Icon I need to wait about 30 to 60 seconds to open program. In meantime nothing happening and just pop up like normal start. Also VLC player (Latest version also), when I open video nothing happens and then after some time it's just start. I have used before Fedora and Manjaro and I didn't have any similar problems.

Here is my Laptop Specs:

```
System:
  Host: nenad-HP Kernel: 5.3.0-24-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.34.1 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP ProBook 640 G1 
  v: A3009DD10303 serial: <root required> 
  Mobo: Hewlett-Packard model: 1993 v: KBC Version 16.39 
  serial: <root required> UEFI: Hewlett-Packard v: L77 Ver. 01.21 
  date: 09/03/2014 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 46.2 Wh condition: 48.4/48.4 Wh (100%) 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i3-4000M bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 
  3: 798 4: 798 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915 
  v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: i915 resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Haswell Mobile v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.1 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-24-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I217-V driver: e1000e 
  IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: 38:63:bb:b9:11:74 
  Device-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi 
  IF: wlo1 state: up mac: 80:19:34:86:21:c6 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 223.57 GiB used: 23.78 GiB (10.6%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Patriot model: Burst size: 223.57 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 218.57 GiB used: 23.77 GiB (10.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 44.0 C mobo: 0.0 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 263 Uptime: 7h 54m Memory: 7.69 GiB used: 2.39 GiB (31.0%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.36
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193298/various-programs-are-starting-slow-on-ubuntu-19-10/1195048#1195048

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start)

Comment: @heynnema Yes. Now all mentions apps run instantly. Weird about why that happened with fresh install but thank you for help.