# Budgie 19.10: Android Studio starts after 25 seconds delay but starts instantly when opened as super user

Tags: android-studio, budgie

I was using Elementary OS before and android studio had no delay in startup but after a fresh install of Ubuntu Budgie 19.10, it starts after 20 seconds delay. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start) but no luck.

Comment: Can we get details on which installation method you used and logs from a startup attempt?