# Apps started slowly once when I started them as a user

Tags: 19.10, 20.04

I have one strange issue... It's heppening to me from ubuntu 19.10, and now It's same with 20.04.
It's related for next two apps:
* WPS office
* cisco anyconnect

Both apps is started very slowly once when I started them, but this heppening only when I started them as a normal user.
If I started them as a sudo user... They are started very quickly.

Do you have any suggestion what can be and how to check what can be.
I tested kubuntu as well... and in kubuntu I don't have any issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the problem discussed here, [[Some applications on Ubuntu 19.10 very slow to start](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184774/some-applications-on-ubuntu-19-10-very-slow-to-start][1])

Along with the previous answers, I found the problem doesn't happen if you choose to Upgrade using the Release-Upgrade method. An easy method would be to install 18.04.4, then from that system install 20.04 by running sudo do-release-upgrade -d
In my case the Internet Upgrade would take about 15 to 20 minutes and afterwards there wasn't any trouble with some Apps starting with a 25 second delay.